# Error Vtex.IO - error: Field 'name' may contain only letters, numbers, underscores and hyphens

Tags: reactjs

everything good? I'm making a Vtex.IO project - https://vtex.io/docs/getting-started/build-stores-with-store-framework/1 - and when I call their command to create the link between the folder on my PC and the Store I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Git\atmosphere> vtex link
```

21:09:36.118 - error: Field 'name' may contain only letters, numbers, underscores and hyphens
PS C:\Git\atmosphere>

I already checked:

Manifest file and is correct.
I'm running as admin
I'm inside the folder where the files are
I installed all the dependencies as they recommended in their Readme

Does anyone have an idea what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

I went through something similar and my manifest file had a space after the name

ex: {
"vendor" : "lorem "
}